# ironRouter onbeforeaction gives 2 errors, but does what I expect it to do

Tags: meteor

Users login using FB or twitter:

I'm trying to check for multiple things here as you can see. But for some reason I get 2 errors:
1. Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
2. Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

The funny thing is, this code IS doing what I expected it to do. Route to completeSignup if profile.firsttime = false and if not logged in go to startPage. But I still get these errors, so I must be doing something wrong.

code:

```
    onBeforeActions = {
    loginRequired: function() {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            Router.go('startPage');
        } else  {
            if (Meteor.userId() && Meteor.user().profile.firsttime) {
                Router.go('completeSignup');
            }
        }

        this.next();
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(onBeforeActions.loginRequired, {
    except: ['startPage']
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Meteor.userId()` becomes available as part of the login process prior to the arrivial of the user document on the client. Mixing the two in the `if` actually doesn't do what you want because, for a brief moment, they won't simultaneously return truthy values.

In order to avoid the error you'll need to add some extra [guards](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). Try something like this in your `else` clause:

```js
var user = Meteor.user();
if (user && user.profile && user.profile.firsttime) {
  Router.go('completeSignup');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! it works, but after reading your article i'm still not sure what 'guards' are. How do you know when to use them?

Comment: You use them any time code can execute where the required objects may or may not actually exist. In this case `user` may be`undefined`. If it is, you can't get `user.profile`, or `user.profile.firsttime` without throwing an error. A guard is a defensive programming mechanism to test whether a required object is defined prior accessing its properties. When we write `user && user.profile`, that means: "If user is defined, return the result of user.profile".

Comment: wow thanks so much for the clarification! that really helped a lot in understanding the why's!